# Is there a way to customise Kampyle, UserVoice, GetSatisfaction or OpinionLab to display the form inline (e.g: not Lightbox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed, user-feedback

The part of the website that I am working on is limited to HTML files only and my customer wants to add a "*Was This Helpful* - **Yes** / **No** " type of feedback message at the end of every help page.

I found a lot of third party scripts but they are all on the fixed either on the left hand side or on the right hand side of the page and the input field is made using Lightbox.

Is there a way to use these scripts and add the form inline something like a flash object or iframe embed code?

( Here I am talking about tools such us: webengage, Kampyle, UserVoice, GetSatisfaction or OpinionLab and so on ).

Answer (score 0):

Kampyle can certainly do this and the feedback button can be easily customized to be a regular HTML link rather than the floating button image.  You can get the standard (floating button) tag from the 'embed URL' page and then customize it like this:

`Was This Helpful  - <a href='https://www.kampyle.com/feedback_form/ff-feedback-form.php?site_code=<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>&amp;form_id=<YOUR_FORM_ID>&amp;lang=en' target='myFrame'>Yes</a>`

You could even have links to two different forms – one for **Yes** and another for **No**.  Each form could then be tailored to establish the reasons behind the different responses.

For a Kampyle account, you can either request a demo on the Kampyle site (http://www.kampyle.com/l/) or email your request to sales@kampyle.com.

*Declaration: I work on the Support Helpdesk Team at Kampyle*